# What happens after i ctr+c during a nohup through ssh?

Tags: unix, ssh, remote-access, nohup

I've some questions about nohup. Below shows the commands and results i've tried. **If i have to use `nohup ... &` and then `disown`, then what's the use of the `nohup`?** I could have simply use `... &` and then `disown`.

**Run a command with `nohup` and then ctr+c , the command didn't continue**

```
$ nohup somecommand -option inputfile > outputfile
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
^C
```

**Run command with `nohup ... &` and then ctr+c, the command continues but stops after exit**

```
$ nohup somecommand -option inputfile > outputfile &
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
^C
$ exit
```

**Run command with `nohup ... &` and then ctr+c, the command continues even after exit**

```
$ nohup somecommand -option inputfile > outputfile &
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
^C
$ disown
$ exit
```

**Run command with without `nohup` and then ctr+c, the command continues even after exit**

```
$ somecommand -option inputfile > outputfile &
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
^C
$ disown
$ exit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we leave `stderr` writing to terminal then `disown` needs to be called to remove this job or all the jobs from the job table.

So make sure you redirect `stdout` and `stderr` both using `nohup` and `&`:

```
nohup somecommand -option inputfile > outputfile 2>&1 &
exit
```

**command would still be running.**

Comment: `2>&1` redirects stderr(fd=2) to where `&1` (refrence to stdout)

Comment: Why? Why redirecting stderr has anything to do with disown and ctrl+c?

Comment: @PedroA: If we leave stderr writing to terminal then `disown` needs to be called to remove a job or all
    jobs from the job table.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the clarification and quick reply (on such an old post!). I recommend editing this info into the answer. Thanks!!